# $(f)(x)$ vs $f(x)$: what is the difference?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, notation

What is the difference between $(f)(x)$ and $f(x)$?

This arose from a problem in which I was given $$T(f)(x) = (x^2)(f(x))$$ and I have to prove it is linear. I've never seen notation like this; is it the same as if there were no parentheses around f?

Comment: What's the context?

Comment: I am given T(f)(x) = (x^2)(f(x)) and I have to prove it is linear. I've just never dealt with it written like this and I am not sure if it would be the same thing if there were no parentheses around f.

Comment: You should have put that information in the question, since the question makes no sense without it. It's not $T$ that's doing something to $(f)(x)$, it's $T(f)$ doing something to $x$...

Answer (score 1):

It indicates that $T$ is a function of two inputs.  It needs a function $f$, and a number $x$ to fully evaluate.  For example,
$$
T(e^x)(3) = 3^2 e^3.
$$
HINT: It is not linear in $x$, but is in $f$.

Comment: Ah I understand now. Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps I'm being a bit pedantic, but $T$ really shouldn't be thought of as a function of two inputs. That suggests $T: F\times \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ where $F$ is some function space. The notation more closely suggests $T:F\to F$ and it's the element $T(f)$ being evaluated at some real number.

Comment: @YiFan Isn't this just an example of [currying](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)? Thus, a function $T\colon F\to F$ can bei identified with a function $T\colon F\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ (assuming $F$ is a subset of the functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$) and they are related by $$(T(f))(x)=T(f,x)$$

Comment: @Filippo You're right, so it's not technically incorrect to say $T$ is a function of two inputs (which is why I said I was being a bit pedantic). My point was that this is not the usual way that one thinks about it, which is as a transformation of the function space. While the maps $F\to F$ and $F\times\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ can be identified by currying, they're not exactly the same per se, and the notation $T(f)(x)$ would seem to suggest the former meaning (composed with evaluation at $x$).